# Moving third party library from header file

Tags: c++11

I have the following code snippet:

```
#include <nats/nats.h>

class MyClass
{
public:
    // some functions here
private:
template<typename T, void (*DestroyFn)(T*)>
decltype(DestroyFn) makeDeleter()
{
    return [](T* ptr)
    {
        DestroyFn(ptr);
    };
}

std::unique_ptr<natsOptions, std::function<void(natsOptions*)>> m_options{
    nullptr,
    makeDeleter<natsOptions, natsOptions_Destroy>()};
std::unique_ptr<natsConnection, std::function<void(natsConnection*)>> m_connection{
    nullptr,
    makeDeleter<natsConnection, natsConnection_Destroy>()};
std::unique_ptr<natsSubscription, std::function<void(natsSubscription*)>> m_subscription{
    nullptr,
    makeDeleter<natsSubscription, natsSubscription_Destroy>()};
};
```

If I wouldn't have required custom deleters I could easily forward declare used types from NATS library. But is it possible to do same if I have `makeDeleter` function template deleter which calls actual functions from the library (e.g., `natsOptions_Destroy`)?
The thing is that the reviewers of the code require to not include 3rd party library in the current header file, but on the other hand I don't see the issue in my case, because current header is included only in two `.cpp` file, hence only two translation units will be recompiled if something changes in the `nats.h`.

Comment: Well, you could omit data member initializers, and initialize them in the constructor initializer list instead (which could be in a source file).

Comment: Will try, thank you @IgorTandetnik. But, I can't leave `std::unique_ptr` uninitialized in the header, correct? I guess it is possible to initialize those by `nullptr` and later, in the constructor, assign deleter.

Comment: Yes, you can leave them without initializer in the header, and initialize them in the constructor. That's how it was done for years, before the in-class initializers were invented (relatively recently).

Comment: After moving 3rd party header to the .cpp now I have the following in my header:
typedef struct natsOptions Options;
std::unique_ptr<Options, std::function<void(Options*)>> m_options;

And I have initialized member in the constructor later in the .cpp.
Unfortunately, I am getting error like:
Error C2664 'natsStatus natsConnection_Connect(natsConnection **,natsOptions *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'bridge::natsConnection **' to 'natsConnection **'
 status = natsConnection_Connect(&connection, options);
        Bridge NatsHandler.cpp 167

The same error applies to other members.

Comment: Or from the output of VS:
'bridge::`anonymous-namespace'::makeDeleter': no matching overloaded function found
: m_options{nullptr, makeDeleter<natsOptions, natsOptions_Destroy>()}

I guess function template should not be moved to .cpp ?

Comment: You forward-declared a wrong type. `::natsConnection != bridge::natsConnection`. Put your forward declaration into the correct namespace.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you very much for your patience and help!